# Best way to define an implicit class that needs a parameter at runtime

Tags: scala, implicit

I have an implicit class that needs to use a given parameter at runtime. So I define this implicit in another class that takes this parameter in the constructor. A simplified version of what I am doing is as follows:

```
case class A(p1: String) {
    def foo = println("foo: " + p1)
}

class B(p2: String) {
    implicit class Enhancer(a: A) {
        implicit def bar = s"bar: ${a.p1}, $p2"
    }
}
```

So when I need to use this class I then do the following:

```
val a = A("x")

val b = new B("y")
import b._

a.bar
```

I am wondering if there is a neater way than the above? Specifically the middle two lines where I define the object and then import from it. For example is there any way I could have a one line call to return the implicit class I need?

Comment: Why not passing `p2` as an argument to `bar`?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Then you'll have to specify `p2` every time you call `bar`.

Comment: @DmytroMitin Well, I may argue that would be better than implicit values flying magically all over the code. Anyways, good answer.

Answer (score 3):

Try to add implicit parameter to `Enhancer`.

```
case class A(p1: String) {
  def foo = println("foo: " + p1)
}

class B(val p2: String)

implicit class Enhancer(a: A)(implicit b: B) {
  implicit def bar = s"bar: ${a.p1}, ${b.p2}"
}

val a = A("x")

implicit object b extends B("y")

a.bar
```

or

```
implicit val b = new B("y")

a.bar
```

Or

```
implicit class Enhancer(val a: A) extends AnyVal {
  implicit def bar(implicit b: B) = s"bar: ${a.p1}, ${b.p2}"
}
```